# Rails 3: how to code a route path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm creating a rails app and I can't figure out or find answer for this problem.

What is the route for:

`@example = Example.find_by_notId(params[:notId])`

I want my route to look better then /example/1 and would rather have it read /notId (where notId would be title or some other non-ID int). Normally I would use show_path but in my html `<%= link_to image_tag(pic), show_path(example) %>` doesn't work. Here is my code and it works when I hard code it into the URL (localhost:3000/notId) but I need a way to route it through a link. Any ideas?

Show

```
def show
   @example = Example.find_by_title(params[:title])
end
```

Routes

```
match '/:notId', to: 'example#show', via: 'get'
```

_example.html.erb

```
<div class="example">
 <% Movie.all.each do |example| %>
  <%pic = example.title + ".jpg"%>
  <%= link_to image_tag(pic), show_path(example) %>
 <% end %>
e</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to override the `:id` param in your routes:

```
resources :examples, param: :title
```

This will generate routes like:

```
/examples/:title
/examples/:title/edit
```

Then in your views:

```
example_path(example.title)
```

Alternatively, you can change the method `to_param`(used for building urls) in your model:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    title
  end
end
```

This allows you to keep using `example_path(example)` (without `.title`)

Comment: Thanks that worked, I just had to change my html to `example_path(example.title)`